# Bootstrap control modals plugin changing icons in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins, layer-control

I'm using Leaflet plugin L.Control.BootstrapModal (see https://github.com/gregallensworth/L.Control.BootstrapModal) to add a few layer controls on my map which toggle a modal displaying some country info as per below:

```
new L.Control.BootstrapModal({
    modalId: 'Modal',
    tooltip: "How to use this thing",
    glyph: 'question-sign'
}).addTo(map);
```

I am wondering how to change the icon of the above.

Comment: `L.Control.BootstrapModal` is not part of vanilla Leaflet. Please edit your question and add info of where it's coming from.

Comment: Hi @TomazicM , it is not, however I have seen it used instead of easy buttons on leaflet apps, and it is working just fine when displaying modals, however, I do not know how to style it (I cannot add it a customized icon).

Comment: As I wrote,  please edit your question and add info of where plugin is coming from.

Comment: @TomazicM I got this plugin from here: https://github.com/gregallensworth/L.Control.BootstrapModal

Answer (score 3):

Plugin uses an older version of Bootstrap v3.3.6. You can find glyphs for this version here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/. You will see that icons are named like `glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk`. To use icon in plugin, you have to set  `glyph` option just to the last part of the name after `-`. In this case it would be `asterisk`.

For example, to use glyph `glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger`, code would look like this:

```
new L.Control.BootstrapModal({
  modalId: 'modal_menu',
  tooltip: "Settings",
  glyph: 'menu-hamburger'
}).addTo(map);
```

This would the look like this:

[image]

Example on plugin docs page uses ages old Leaflet v0.7.7. You can use the latest Leaflet v1.9.3 and it will still work.